# Error deserializing Avro message on Sink Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

I am getting error deserializing Avro message while trying to consume avro message from topic and dump them into postgres DB.

Here is my Producer config:

> ```
> spring
>   Kafka
>     producer:
>       bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
>       key-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
>       value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
>       properties:
>         schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
> ```

sink-connector config:

> ```
> {
> "name": "jdbc_source_postgres_avro",
> "config": {
>     "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
>     "connection.url": "jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/kafka-test",
>     "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
>     "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
>     "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
>     "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
>     "connection.user": "postgres",
>     "connection.password": "password",
>     "topics": "docker-avro-topic",
>     "auto.create": "true",
>     "auto.offset.reset": "latest",
>     "name": "jdbc_source_postgres_avro"
> }
> ```

docker-image for connect:

> ```
> connect:
> image: cnfldemos/kafka-connect-datagen:0.1.3-5.3.1
> hostname: connect
> container_name: connect
> depends_on:
>   - zookeeper
>   - broker
>   - schema-registry
> ports:
>   - "8083:8083"
> environment:
>   CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
>   CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
>   CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
>   CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
>   CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
>   CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
>   CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
>   CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
>   CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
>   CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
>   CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
>   CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
>   CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
>   CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
>   CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
>   CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
>   CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
>   CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
>   CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
> ```

And finally the error log:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded
in error handler    at
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
    at
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:487)
    at
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:464)
    at
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:320)
    at
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
    at
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
    at
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
    at
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
    at
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize
data for topic docker-avro-topic to Avro:   at
io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:110)
    at
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:487)
    at
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)...
13 more Caused by:
**org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
deserializing Avro message for id 101 Caused by:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)  at
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)**     at
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)    at
sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)     at
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)     at
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)     at
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)     at
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)    at
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357     at
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at
java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
```

Answer (score 3):

You've configured Kafka Connect to look for a Schema Registry that is running on the same container:

```
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
```

but it's not, hence:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Since you've already specified the Schema Registry config in your Kafka Connect docker environment variables then assuming you actually do have the Schema Registry running on a container that can be resolved as `schema-registry` from the Kafka Connect container, you can simply remove the `schema.registry.url` configuration lines from the actual Connector configuration.

Comment: I tried without out schema.registry.url, but it failed saying that it couldn't find/missing schema.registry.url. So gave "http://schema-registry:8081" instead of localhost and it worked!!

Comment: Im getting error saying that "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/"

How do i install postgres driver on docker container, or give reference of my local path?!!

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer as correct, and start a new question for your new question :)

Comment: @Oviyan Postgres driver already is part of the Confluent docker containers. You should search Confluent Github for `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH` anyway

Comment: @cricket_007: i already have below config, should i add any other path?

CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-5.3.1.jar
CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"

Comment: @Oviyan can you exec into the container and find the Postgres driver under /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc?

Comment: @cricket_007:ouch! i can see only kafka folder. So i moved jars file into docker-image
root@broker:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc#. I can also see postgresql-9.4.1212.jar . However, im still getting same issue.

Comment: @Oviyan I would suggest using `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect` as your base image, then, rather than `cnfldemos/kafka-connect-datagen:0.1.3-5.3.1`